# How to design an enum common to multiple platforms, but with different configurations per platform

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum already implemented in my code for AWS Provider:

```java
public enum LevelsAWS {

    ALERT("0.0", "0.0"),
    HIGH("1e-8", "1e-7", "0"),
    MEDIUM("1e-6", "1e-5", "1"),
    LOW("1e-4", "1e-3", "2");

    String level;
    String levelAuto;
    String levelStr;

    HighriskLevels(String level, String levelAuto) {
        this.level = level;
        this.levelAuto = levelAuto;
    }

    HighriskLevels(String level, String levelAuto,
                   String levelStr) {
        this.level = level;
        this.levelAuto = levelAuto;
        this.levelStr = levelStr;
    }

    public String getLevel() {return level;}

    public String getLevelAuto() {return levelAuto;}

    public String getLevelStr() {return levelStr;}

}
```

Now, I am extending my logic to other providers like Azure and GCP, and I need similar enums for them as well, but the values specified for each enum object will be different. For example, for Azure it could be:

```java
public enum LevelsAZURE {

    ALERT("1.0", "1.0"),
    HIGH("1e-160", "1e-175", "0"),
    MEDIUM("1e-110", "1e-125", "1"),
    LOW("1e-12", "1e-15", "2");

    String level;
    String levelAuto;
    String levelStr;

    HighriskLevels(String level, String levelAuto) {
        this.level = level;
        this.levelAuto = levelAuto;
    }

    HighriskLevels(String level, String levelAuto,
                   String levelStr) {
        this.level = level;
        this.levelAuto = levelAuto;
        this.levelStr = levelStr;
    }

    public String getLevel() {return level;}

    public String getLevelAuto() {return levelAuto;}

    public String getLevelStr() {return levelStr;}

}
```

This would obviously work, however repeats a lot of code. What's a more object oriented way to achieve the same?

Comment: I think I would use enums without values, and a repository to look up a record/object with the levels for a specific platform for that enum value. As an aside, why are these levels defined as strings, and not as double, float or int?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have implemented in a similar way where I use a repo to look up.
The values specified are default values if there is nothing found during lookup. Perhaps I should define the default values in some other way?

Comment: The parts that change should be separate from the parts that stay the same, and you should have a separate (single) interface to map to and from as needed.

Comment: That sounds like a fallback scenario that also belongs in the platform specific repository.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different possible design, below design aim on:

1. Minimise code duplication
2. Reduce effort to add new platform or alert level
3. Missing value will lead to compile error when adding new `Platform` thanks to [switch expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/switch-expressions.html).

```
public enum Platform {
    AWS, GCP
}
public enum PlatformDefaultLevel {
    ALERT {
        @Override
        public Level getPlatformLevel(Platform platform) {
            return switch (platform) {
                case AWS -> new Level("0.0", "0.0", null);
                case GCP -> new Level("1.0", "1.0", null);
            };
        }
    },
    HIGH {
        // do similarly
    },
    MEDIUM {
        // do similarly
    },
    LOW {
        // do similarly
    };

    record Level(String level, String levelAuto, String levelString) {
    }

    protected abstract Level getPlatformLevel(Platform platform);

    public String getLevel(Platform platform) {
        return getPlatformLevel(platform).level();
    }

    public String getLevelAuto(Platform platform) {
        return getPlatformLevel(platform).levelAuto();
    }

    public String getLevelStr(Platform platform) {
        return getPlatformLevel(platform).levelString();
    }
}
```